# Custom webpack config in angular esbuild

Tags: angular, webpack, esbuild

Currently my Angular project uses a custom webpack configuration file.

```
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
                ...
            ],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./angular-webpack.config.js",
              "mergeRules": {
                "module": {
                  "rules": "prepend"
                }
              }
            },
```

And inside my custom configuration I am using some custom environment variables from mt build.
But I want to move over to esbuild, but the issue is that I can't find any good/obvious way to have some custom esbuild config for Angular.

```
let DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
let OS = require('os');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new DefinePlugin({
            VERSION: JSON.stringify(process.env.VERSION || OS.hostname()),
            URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.URL || ''),
        }),
    ],
}
```

Any help or tips are appreciated of how I should go about implementing custom defined environment variables for Angular esbuild.

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to define a custom env variable for your app using Webpack define plugin ?

Comment: I want to move to esbuild for Angular. No webpack. But I need to pass in the two environment variables that was used in Webpack. So basically esbuild + environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment (Angular 17.1), esbuild-based Angular builders do not officially support changes to esbuild and Vite configs, which, if available, would enable passing environment variables to the built application.

As a workaround, you could use obscure `executeDevServerBuilder` and `createBuilder` APIs to wrap the default builders and inject esbuild plugins [into the fourth argument](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/8216b11b3cff5b0c37afd4dac6aa61851f24849a/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/builders/dev-server/builder.ts#L45) of `executeDevServerBuilder`, like [esbuild-plugin-define](https://github.com/webdeveric/esbuild-plugin-define):

```js
const { executeDevServerBuilder } = require("@angular-devkit/build-angular");
const { createBuilder } = require("@angular-devkit/architect");
const { definePlugin } = require('esbuild-plugin-define')

const builder = function (options, context) {
  return executeDevServerBuilder(options, context, undefined, {
    buildPlugins: [definePlugin({
        process: {
          env: {
            BUILD_TIMESTAMP: process.env.BUILD_TIMESTAMP,
          },
        },
      })]
  });
};
module.exports = createBuilder(builder);
```

[Here's an article](https://blog.devgenius.io/extending-angular-cli-f8b1abeb612a) that explains the process of wrapping a builder in more detail.

Fortunately, you don't have to make your own wrapper, the [dot-env](https://github.com/chihab/dotenv-run) package does [exactly that](https://github.com/chihab/dotenv-run/blob/a614db48e37c730dc3bd72979a17f250d406078f/packages/angular/src/builders/dev-server/index.ts#L70).

Comment: Where do you put this code? and how do you link this code to the cli? and then how do you set the the variable in `environment.ts`?